# asp.net identity login page login will work after visiting register then back to login page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

I have come across something very strange and just cannot figure it out.  I have a web forms app in C# created in VS 2015 using 4.5 framework.  I have made no changes to the login page or login.cs at all.

I start up the site, enter my valid login credentials, and hit enter.  Page just goes to the default page and I am not logged in.  BUT if I go to the register page by clicking the register link and then go back to login and enter my valid credentials I am logged in as expected.

As I said, I have made no changes to the login form or cs file.  Very odd behavior.  Has anyone encountered something like this?

Answer (score 1):

So I figured if anyone sees this and has the same issue I can hopefully help them.  In my instance it was the botdetect captcha causing the issue.

Removing "sessionIDManagerType="BotDetect.Web.CustomSessionIdManager, BotDetect" resolved my issue.